# Default Running

Tags: 12.04, wine, default

I want to make my Minecraft Skin Viewer not have to be put into the Terminal like

```
User@ChrUbuntu~$ Wine '/home/user/Documents/MCSV.exe'
```

I just want to be able to double click the .exe file and it will run.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi If you have already installed wine in  your Ubuntu then you will have the option in the right click. I mean look at the image

[image]
Just go the Properties and select wine application as the default instead of other things . I mean wine should be 1st choice in the row & don't forget giving executable permissions for the application which you would like to run.

Then automatically with double-click , you will get it.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a script is an easy way of achieving what you want:

1) In GEdit (the text editor) write the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

wine ~/Documents/MCSV.exe
```

2) Save it in a place of your choice (e.i., in your home folder or your desktop).

3) Right-click the script and go to **Properties**.

4) In the **Permissions** tab check *Allow executing file as program*.

Now you can double click the file. If you want it to appear in the Dash you should create a ".desktop" file.